# What factors contribute to the memory used while writing Spark Data frame to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark 1.6 and have two data frames, df1 and df2. Both of these columns have the exact same columns(71 in number) and schema(All columns are String Type).

df1 has 241 million rows whereas df2 has 245 million rows.

While writing these dataframes to HDFS using databricks csv package, df1 takes up 165 GB of disk space whereas df2 takes up 800+ GB.

```
(df
    .write
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
    .option("sep", "\x01")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save(path)
)
```

What can explain such a large difference(5x) when the two dataframes have comparable rows and exact same columns.

Comment: How do you know what is the content of the dataframe ? Maybe the df2 has more data than df1. Even if they have same column they could have different content. Like all the columns of df1 has very less data whereas df2 has more

Comment: What is the size of your original data in GBs? What is the size of RDD (create RDD from DF1/DF2) in GBs? Number of rows and number of columns are not the true indicator of data size and specially when the columns is of type "String". Example: "aa" is a string as well as "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa". But based on that can we say that they are of comparable size? No.